# Custom Record Reader in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

**High Level Scenario :** I am working on a Proof of concept where I need to stream content of some log files and execute CEP patterns on those Data Streams.

**Situation :** By Default, Flink StreamExecutionEnvironment.readTextFile() reads each line of a given file and creates a Data Stream object. For some of our files, we would like to get multiple lines together and combine them into a single Data Stream object. I believe we need to implement a custom record reader in Apache Flink, but unable to find any example for the same.

Any help / suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by multiple lines? Do you have a file where instead of reading it line by line you want to always read, for instance, 5 lines every time?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. But no, I can not always read fixed number of lines. Sometimes its just 1 line and sometimes a number of consecutive lines matching a specific pattern.

Comment: It might be useful to add an example of lines that need to be grouped together and how CEP comes into the picture.